# Excel 365 - Can a pivot table be linked to a table in another excel 365 workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two workbooks in OneDrive. I want one file to contain pivot tables, and the second to store raw data in a table. Is it possible to link the pivot tables to the data table in the second workbook? I can link cells from one workbook to another but haven't found a way to do this for pivot tables.

I have this setup desktop version, but wondering if possible to do online.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am not sure whether you can do this from the online version of Excel, but if you open both files on the desktop version, it is possible to have the data source in one workbook and the PivotTable in another workbook. Are you able to do this via the desktop version of Excel? Once you set it up via the desktop version, I am unsure how this functions once you access it via MSFT 365. However, it would be easy to set it up via the desktop version and then see what happens online.

Comment: @gswanson ,, yes is possible either use Power Query to combine all data sources or create Connection ,,,, then use Power Pivot ☺

Comment: Do you mean add the data from another Workbook into data model?